# Java blur translucent background

Tags: java, transparency, blur

How can I blur the background of my translucent JFrame?

The background of my JFrame is a label which has an image as its icon. I make the picture transparent, but now I want to make it blurred (almost like the blur at the top of windows frames).

```
float[] matrix = {
        0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
        0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
        0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
    };

    BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp( new Kernel(3, 3, matrix) );
    blurredImage = op.filter(sourceImage, destImage);
```

I was thinking this might work, but I want to blur my image temporarily (as long as the JFrame is open). What can I do? I've tried researching this and can't find anything that suits me. Keep in mind I'm quite new to JFrames.

Comment: Could you maybe layer it under some other translucent component with a hue on it, say dark grey, or a slight black hue? It might not be 'blurred' but will give the distinct impression that its disabled I think...

Comment: I am on Windows, but I do not see the blur mentioned. Could you provide some pictures?